# Mysql вывести записи в названии которых есть искомое слово

Tags: mysql

В таблице есть три записи, где одно из полей "имя". 
Петя, Вася, Вова

Как вывести запись с именем Петя если искомое слово "Пет"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name = 'Пет';

SELECT * FROM `people` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."';
```